# Usando regex (PHP) como limitar a busca a um grupo de texto?

Tags: php

Considerando a hipótese de texto (com e sem separação por parágrafos - para cada grupo cujo conteúdo se repete):

**grupo1**, tiago, bola, mola, tijolo, pedro, bola, mola, tijolo, raimundo, bola, mola, tijolo, joao, bola, mola, tijolo, felipe, bola, mola, tijolo,

**grupo2**, tiago, bola, mola, tijolo, pedro, bola, mola, tijolo raimundo, bola, mola, tijolo, joao, bola, mola, tijolo, felipe, bola, mola, tijolo,

**grupo3**, tiago, bola, mola, tijolo, pedro, bola, mola, tijolo raimundo, bola, mola, tijolo, joao, bola, mola, tijolo, felipe, bola, mola, tijolo,

**grupo4**, tiago, bola, mola, tijolo, pedro, bola, mola, tijolo raimundo, bola, mola, tijolo, joao, bola, mola, tijolo, felipe, bola, mola, tijolo,

**grupo5**, tiago, bola, mola, tijolo, pedro, bola, mola, tijolo raimundo, bola, mola, tijolo, joao, bola, mola, tijolo, felipe, bola, mola, tijolo,

Usando regex (`PHP`) **como limitar a busca ao que está entre o grupo3 e grupo4** para que minha saída seja em subgrupos das pessoas:

tiago bola mola tijolo

pedro bola mola tijolo

raimundo bola mola tijolo

joao bola mola tijolo

felipe bola mola tijolo

Comment: eu nao entendi direito... apenas do grupo 3 você quer remover as vírgulas, é isso?

Comment: @LeoNogueira, editei para tentar deixar mais clara a questão.

Comment: Essa pergunta foi respondida em: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46820143/regex-php-how-to-limit-variable-search-to-a-single-paragraph/46826042#46826042